# Why do Christian's associate Jesus as the son of God?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Hi to the Christian community.

I've always wondered why Christian's associate Jesus as the son of God? Let me elaborate. I am Muslim, and in Islam we believe that God has no partner. He is alone.

> Praise be to Allah, Who hath not taken unto Himself a son, and Who hath no partner in the Sovereignty, nor hath He any protecting friend through dependence. And magnify Him with all magnificence. (Chapter (17) sūrat l-isrā (The Night Journey))

In Christianity Jesus is referred to as 'Son of God'. To have a son - God had to have some sort of sexual relation right? If Jesus is a human, what is God? Could someone please 'kindly' explain? Thanks and would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: To answer your question there are two Christian tenants which need to be understood.  First is the incarnation of the logos.  Second is the trinity.  Both are complex ideas and are not necessarily agreed on by all Christian denominations - therefore, is there a specific denomination which you would like an answer from?  Consider this as asking a question about the nature of Allah and Mohammad to a Sunni or Shia Muslim.  Secondly, I truly appreciate your activity here and I welcome and encourage you to join in this SE.  We are all children of God attempting to understand his nature and will.

Comment: Helpful and related: [Can Muslims consider Isa the “Spiritual” son of God?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14620/6581)

Comment: An omnipotent deity can surely create a Son without the need for sexual relations in the sense you envisage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments stated, in order to understand why Christians believe Jesus to be the 'Son of God', you'll want to grasp the concepts of the Incarnation of the Logos (God's Word, also sometimes referred to as the 'Wisdom of God' assuming flesh). And the trinity, which is the concept that there are three Persons in a single being. This is a difficult thing for most of make sense out of and explain accurately. I have heard this explained that God's thoughts are so perfect that being aware of Himself actually constitutes a Second Person. In other words, His wisdom is so Perfect it itself becomes a Person. These two Persons Love one another so Perfectly that that Love itself also is a Third person. All three are still of the same being, constituted by the same 'beingness' and drawing upon the same source of power. This is how God can be 3 Persons but still 1.

A man named St. Thomas Aquinas gave an analogy to explain how in the world God could assume a human form: It's LIKE (and not the same as) when you have a dream, the entire dream world is a product of your thoughts. You yourself assume the limitations of this dream world and enter it and experience it. Since God thought the world into existence, its kind of LIKE God did something similar.

The documents of the New testament detail the life and teachings of Jesus; in which He claims quite explicitly that He is one with the Creator. There are hints in the Old testament that support this concept. Jesus' claim to be God is why He was singled out for Crucifixion by His own people; where as other people who claimed to be the Messiah weren't: nobody else made such a claim. And without such a claim, why would His own people want Him dead? Christians have to decide their answer to this dilemma: Either Jesus was crazy, a deceiver or exactly what He said He was.

The title Son of God is used for a few reasons. In our sacred scriptures, having a son means passing on one's own nature. Therefore, to be the Son of God is possess the same nature as God. Since the body of Jesus was conceived by the power of God (and not by a sexual act, since God has no physical body), you could also say Jesus is a Son in this way. There are other reasons too, but this is getting a bit long.

I hope this helps, I know I said a lot for background's sake. For a better explanation on the Trinity, I'd look at some stuff by Father Mike Spitzer. I am reciting from memory his explanations; but reading it yourself may be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not all denominations of Christianity give the same answer to this question. But probably all Christians can agree that we believe Jesus to be the Son of God, because he *said* he was, and the Scriptures repeatedly tell us that's who he is:

> "For **God** so loved the world, that he **gave his only begotten Son**, that
>   whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting
>   life." [(John 3:16)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/john/3.16?lang=eng#15)

See, ["Jesus Christ, Divine Sonship"](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/tg/jesus-christ-divine-sonship?lang=eng) for many more scriptures.

Answer (score -6):

Just as God created the universe, the angels and physical creatures he created Jesus. In Colossians 1:15 Jesus is called the

> "firstborn of all creation"

and in verse 16

> "For by Him all things were created, both in the heavens and on earth,
>   visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or
>   authorities-- all things have been created through Him and for Him"

so, Jesus was the first creation by God and he was his "master worker" as stated in Proverbs 8:30. So since he is the only creation directly made by God he is called the "Son of God". There are other reasons as well for calling him this but that could be really a really long comment.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Correct me if I'm wrong, but wasn't Adam created first?

Comment: Jesus being created is not consistent with all Christian denominations.

Comment: @TheFreemason Could you elaborate? I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean? What is a denomination?

Comment: @TheFreemason Okay I've just read your comment above and now I understand what you mean.

Comment: The doctrine of the trinity states that God (the Godhead), Jesus (the word), and the holy spirit are one.  Therefore, before Jesus was flesh (the incarnation of the logos) he existed.  For example, how could God create God?  http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/where-was-jesus-before-the-events-of-the-new-testament

Comment: Please consider joining our chat for further discussions as to not have extended discussions in comments (makes the question look like a mess).  Thank you for trying to understand the Christian religion.  The Abrahamic religions really should try to better understand each other.  In doing so, we'd find that they are not all that different - especially in how to live peacefully with God's creatures.  I'm not a good representative of the Christian faith - but understand many of the rites, beliefs, and rituals.  Similarly I've studied Islam and Judaism. I am a student of God.

Comment: @TheFreemason fyi, users require at least 20 rep to participate in site chat rooms - it's not particularly helpful to ask people to do something that they aren't currently able to do.

Comment: Thanks and good point.  Since he's in islam.SE, he should get 100 points for registering.